# Adding Fragment to back stack (getting a blank screen on back press)

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have two fragments, first is called Summer Jobs Fragment which contains a list of items and the second is called Summer Jobs Details Frgment which contains a the details of each item. Im trying to set back trace so that when I press the back button from Summer Jobs Detail Fragment I go back to Summer Jobs Fragment.

here is my code for the initial transition from SJF to SJDF:

```
public void onItemClick(
                    AdapterView<?>parent,View view, int position, long id) {

                SummerJobDetailsFragment.mMyAppsBundle.
                        putInt("value", position);
                SummerJobDetailsFragment fragment =
                        new SummerJobDetailsFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager =
                        getFragmentManager();
                list.setVisibility(parent.INVISIBLE);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.displayjobs_detailed, fragment).
                        addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();

            }
```

and here is how I modified the OnBackPressed() in the main:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();

        }
    }
```

But when I press the back key from SJDF I get a blank screen :

[image: list view details]
[image: After back is pressed]

Comment: There is option to post codes !

Comment: yeah I was getting an error about my code turns out it was because I had to many images. I will re post my post

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I edit my post

Comment: Put adapter setting codes in `onResume()`.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna could you elamorate?

Answer (score 6):

fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack() <--dont include this for your first fragment.-->

```
if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() !=1){
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this code in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count <= 1) {
        finish();           
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}
```

Maybe you need to use getSupportFragmentManager() instead.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situations, populate the ListView in `onResume()` method, like

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, List<yourItem>);    
        yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: and then should I call the method inside the onItemckicked(). and if yes should I remove the line that sets the first fragment to invisible?

Comment: @dadadodo No may be not needed if you are sure they are not the cause of happening such. If you feel uncomfortable in setting adapter in onResume then you can create a method to set the adapter and call that in onResume.